# Extract MPEG7 visual descriptors with Java

Tags: java

How would one generate/extract MPEG7 visual descriptors from many images for storage (XMLtype) and later search?

I've tried LIRE but the thing is poorly documented and only includes 3 MPEG7 visual descriptors in their libraries.

Any suggestions on a good Java CBIR library available online?

Thank you